# Tools for performance evaluation of Xen, OpenVZ and XenServer?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, xen, openvz

I want a comparison between Xen, OpenVZ and XenServer. I successfully installed these three and loaded a Debian VM. Please suggest some methods and tools for the performance evaluation of these three. Waiting for your response any suggestions will be really helpful. I really needed some tools or methods for evaluation. Please help.

Thanks

Yedhu Sastri

Answer (score 0):

There lots of ways you can approach performance testing to begin with. If you share your goals it might be easier to suggest more. Here are the tools I've been using:

**1. Disk Performance**

I use bonnie++ from http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/ to get the baseline disk performance metric for the host and every VM:

```
$ bonnie++  -u root -s 200000 -n 10000 -x 1 -f -d /testdisk/testdir
```

Where:

```
-s test data set size in Mb. Use at least twice the amount of RAM,
   or better 80% of available disk space
-d test data set location (use the drive where you placed VMs on Host)
```

Resulting output is the list of coma-separated values like this:
`testedhost.local,200000M,,,37805,11,27388,5,,,62129,4,259.5,0,1000,16993,37,334825,99,872,1,14232,31,440769,99,463,1`

To visualize what this actually means, load to excel or convert csv values to html (paste the above line):

```
bon_csv2html >bonnie.html
```

**2. LAMP stack performance (Apache + MySQL/PostgreSQL)**

Setup the DVD store web application in your VMs: http://linux.dell.com/dvdstore/ and then quickly stress it with an http test tools, ie Apache ab or httperf:

```
ab -n 100000 -c 100 -t 1 -k "testsite.local"
```

Where:

```
-n number of HTTP requests
-c number of concurrent connections
-t number of seconds of the test
```

There is also a more sophisticated stress testing client(called driver) as part of DVD store, that can perform test scenarios like clients and orders creation. Test results will depend on how you setup the application, ie database, apache. Generally you'd want to adjust settings to take advantage of all resources available in tested VMs.

DVD store setup is complex, but worth the efforts since this is an example of real life application, not a synthetic test.